# html specification

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I cannot seem to find a link for a HTML api.

I want to see element.innerHtml, element.OuterHtML. Basically all methods I can invoke in a javascript function to get an elements rendered/not rendered text. Thank you very much

Comment: Are you looking for the HTML reference or the DOM API reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the DOM API.

You can find it on the [w3 site](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR).

The [HTML specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) is about the structure of the HTML document, not how to access it with `innerHTML` and other methods.

Answer (score 3):

Try out : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element

MDC Doc center is a great reference to use for everything relative to HTML. You can generally find the pages from MDC directly from google. Here I searched "element MDC"

Cheers,

-stan

Comment: The only issue with the mozilla documentation is that it will on occasion relate to firefox specific behavior.

Comment: True! Still very useful in many cases. But to use with care as pointed by Oded.

Answer (score 1):

You want the spec for the Document Object Model.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html
- http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR

A cleaner list can be found here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element

Answer (score 1):

There is the [W3C DOM Level 2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/) specification which documents some of the bindings you may be interested in. (Seven years ago I put this into a more browsable format here: http://objjob.phrogz.net/html/hierarchy)

However, some of the properties you discuss, such as `innerHTML` are considered "DOM Level 0". They were implemented by browsers before there was a standard.

You might also be interested in the [MSDN DHTML reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050%28VS.85%29.aspx), which documents properties, methods, and more supported by various versions of IE. While some of them are non-standard, the documentation these days generally indicates which items are standard and which are proprietary extensions.

Finally, there is the [Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) which provides good information from Mozilla.